# Liquibase fails to perform migration due to "duplicate" index on PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a Liquibase migration as part of my Spring Boot application to initialize my database. For development purposes, under the H2 in-memory database, Liquibase has performed the migration without any issues. However, when I run it against a PostgreSQL database, Liquibase fails to migrate as PostgreSQL returns the following:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "idx_channel_id" already exists

Note that the table on which the index is being applied is brand new, and there are no other indexes with the same name in the Liquibase migration file. If I remove this index creation, it just fails on the next one. If I remove the indexes (or move them to a separate migration which is excluded via precondition from invoking on PostgreSQL databases), the migration succeeds but with no indexes at all.

I've been scratching my head at this one and I'm stuck. Full Liquibase migration below:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: rmorrison
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: shouts
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: bigint
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: discord_id
                  type: varchar(18)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: author_id
                  type: varchar(18)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: channel_id
                  type: varchar(18)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: guild_nickname
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: content
                  type: varchar(2000)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: created
                  type: blob
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
        - createTable:
            tableName: contexts
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: bigint
                  autoIncrement: true
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: discord_id
                  type: varchar(18)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: author_id
                  type: varchar(18)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: guild_nickname
                  type: varchar(255)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: content
                  type: varchar(2000)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: created
                  type: blob
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
        - createTable:
            tableName: shouts_contexts
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: shout_id
                  type: bigint
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: context_id
                  type: bigint
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
        - createIndex:
            indexName: idx_channel_id
            tableName: shouts
            unique: false
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: channel_id
                  type: varchar(18)
        - createIndex:
            indexName: idx_author_channel_id
            tableName: shouts
            unique: false
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: author_id
                  type: varchar(18)
              - column:
                  name: channel_id
                  type: varchar(18)
        - createIndex:
            indexName: idx_content
            tableName: shouts
            unique: true
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: content
                  type: varchar(2000)
```

EDIT: I re-configured PostgreSQL to enable statement logging and am now seeing this - looks like this may not be Liquibase after all. Continuing to investigate...

```
< 2017-05-27 19:13:19.697 EDT > LOG:  execute <unnamed>: BEGIN
< 2017-05-27 19:13:19.698 EDT > LOG:  execute <unnamed>: CREATE TABLE public.shouts (id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, discord_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL, author_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL, channel_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL, guild_nickname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, content VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, created OID NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_SHOUTS PRIMARY KEY (id))
< 2017-05-27 19:13:19.718 EDT > LOG:  execute <unnamed>: CREATE TABLE public.contexts (id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, discord_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL, author_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL, guild_nickname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, content VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, created OID NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_CONTEXTS PRIMARY KEY (id))
< 2017-05-27 19:13:19.725 EDT > LOG:  execute <unnamed>: CREATE TABLE public.shouts_contexts (shout_id BIGINT NOT NULL, context_id BIGINT NOT NULL)
< 2017-05-27 19:13:19.727 EDT > LOG:  execute <unnamed>: CREATE INDEX idx_channel_id ON public.shouts(channel_id)
< 2017-05-27 19:13:19.727 EDT > ERROR:  relation "idx_channel_id" already exists
< 2017-05-27 19:13:19.727 EDT > STATEMENT:  CREATE INDEX idx_channel_id ON public.shouts(channel_id)
< 2017-05-27 19:13:19.741 EDT > LOG:  execute S_1: ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. It turns out PostgreSQL requires index names to be unique across tables. I had a "backup" table with old data with the same index name causing a conflict. I removed the offending table and the migration succeeds without issue now.